# How to get an instance of a thread from its name/id?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to get the instance of a specific running thread knowing its name or id? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's a more direct way but in the worst case you should be able to loop through all the threads in `Process.Threads` and checking the `ProcessThread.Id` of them.

Here's the MSDN doc for [ProcessThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread_properties.aspx) properties.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like I can only do my comparison based  on the ids, not the names of the threads (Thread.Name).

Comment: @Amokrane: Yes, I get the feeling that that's by design. I've never set a thread's name and looking around it seems like that feature is mostly for debugging purposes. I haven't seen anything saying that outright but you can get indications here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/2a754d46-84d0-45ec-a7bf-58e22331e1c2 and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score -3):

You could try something like this:

```
Thread thread = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Single(t => t.ManagedThreadId == threadId);
```

Comment: -1 because a `ProcessThread`, which is what `Process.Threads` is a collection of, doesn't have a `ManagedThreadId` property.

Comment: -1 because `Process.Threads` is not an `IEnumerable` and therefore `.Single(...)` does not work.

Comment: @tomfanning While the `InnerList` property contains a `ArrayList` of `ProcessThread` objects, enumerating `Threads` will actually return `Thread` objects, there is no `Single()` function though..

Comment: Hi all. Sorry you are right. I didn't notice that Thread is a ReadOnlyCollection and is only IEnumerable.

Answer (score -4):

You forgot to use Cast.

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>().Single(t => t.ManagedThreadId == threadId);
```

Comment: No. This gives an exception. The cast is invalid.

Comment: The cast type is wrong is wrong, use instead `.Cast<Thread>()`, this should work

Comment: @yoelhalb No, that also results in an invalid cast exception. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx says ProcessThread does not derive from System.Threading.Thread